# How to derive $X \setminus \bigcap_{k=1}^n U_k = \bigcup_{k=1}^n (X\setminus U_k) $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$X \setminus \bigcap_{k=1}^n U_k  = \bigcup_{k=1}^n (X\setminus U_k) $$

$X$ is any set and $U_1...U_n$ are subsets of X.
How can this two sides are equal?  It makes sense when I think of it in terms of venn diagrams but which property of union is used to derive right hand side?

Comment: How could you show this for $n=2$?

Comment: @B.Mehta: Actually it seems to me that the case $n=2$ is all that is needed. The general case can be then proved using induction on $n$, where $n=2$ is used in the inductive step (also using associativity of union and intersection).

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to hint OP towards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can derive it directly by just looking at the definitions of both sides: 
$$ x \in X \setminus \bigcap_{k=1}^n U_k \Leftrightarrow x \in X, x \not \in \bigcap_{k=1}^n U_k \Leftrightarrow x \in X, \exists k^* \text{ s.t. } x\not \in U_{k^*} \Leftrightarrow x \in X,\exists k^* \text{ s.t. } x \in (X \setminus U_{k^*}) \Leftrightarrow x\in \bigcup_{k=1}^n (X \setminus U_k)   $$

Comment: Ok I can prove it but how it is derived?

Comment: Every step in this proof is just explicitly writing the definition, this is deriving a step from the other. This means that this proof is how to derive the property.

Comment: Read it from left to right, changing $ \Leftrightarrow $ for $ \Rightarrow$ , after this, read it from right to left, this should be clarifying. Each step just uses definitions, thus 'deriving' the property.